# Issues with 'address already in use' (EADDRINUSE) with 'bind' system call in different contexts

Tags: c, sockets, bind, system-calls

After ripping the implementation code for a simple socket-programmed server from Beej's network guide, I can execute the server and its client without any issues.

However, after moving a portion of the out of the 'main' method and into its own function, the programming will fail on its call to bind because of EADDRINUSE every time, without exception - including the same conditions in which it had worked previously.  I can run either executable (before & after change) and one will always work while the other will fail on the bind call.

I am conspicuously aware of the fact that I may have committed a simple oversight and that the solution here is trivial - I would be happy to learn that because I am confused by these results.  Please take a look:

Here is the original code:

```
...
 21 void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
 22 {
 23     if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
 24         return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
 25     }
 26
 27     return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr); // IPv6
 28 }

...
 38
 37     if ((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
 36         fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
 35         exit(1);
 34     }
 33
 32     // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
 31     for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
 30         if ((sock_fd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
 29                 p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
 28             perror("server: socket");
 27             continue;
 26         }
 25         printf("socket num: %d\n", sock_fd);
 24
 23         if (setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
 22                 sizeof(int)) == -1) {
 21             perror("setsockopt");
 20             exit(1);
 19         }
 18
 17         if (bind(sock_fd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
 16             close(sock_fd);
 15             perror("server: bind");
 14             continue;
 13         }
 12         printf("\nsa_family, sa_data, p->ai_addrlen: %d, %s, %d\n",
 11                 p->ai_addr->sa_family, p->ai_addr->sa_data, p->ai_addrlen);
 10
  9         break;
  8     }
  7
  6     freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure
  5
  4     if (p == NULL) {
  3         fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind to valid addrinfo");
  2         exit(1);
  1     }
...
```

and its output:

```
socket num: 4

, 28amily, sa_data, p->ai_addrlen: 30,
server: waiting for connections...
^C
```

Here is the altered code;

```
 32 struct addrinfo * find_server(int *sock_fd, struct addrinfo *servinfo) {
 31     int yes = 1;
 30     struct addrinfo *p;
 29
 28     for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
 27       if ((*sock_fd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
 26         perror("server: socket");
 25         continue;
 24       }
 23       printf("socket num: %d\n", *sock_fd);
 22       if (setsockopt(*sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
 21         perror("server: setsockopt");
 20         exit(1);
 19       }
 18       if (bind(*sock_fd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
 17         printf("sa_family, sa_data, p->ai_addrlen: %d, %s, %d\n",
 16                 p->ai_addr->sa_family, p->ai_addr->sa_data, p->ai_addrlen);
 15
 14         close(*sock_fd);
 13         perror("server: bind");
 12         continue;
 11       }
 10     }
  9     free(servinfo);
  8
  7     return p;
  6 }
...
  5     if ((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
  4         fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
  3         exit(1);
  2     }
  1
173     if ((p = find_server(&sock_fd, servinfo)) == NULL) {
  1         fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind to valid addrinfo");
  2         exit(1);
  3     }
  4
  5     if (listen(sock_fd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
  6         perror("listen");
  7         exit(1);
  8     }
...
```

And its output:

```
socket num: 4
socket num: 5
, 16amily, sa_data, p->ai_addrlen: 2,
server: bind: Address already in use
server: failed to bind to valid addrinfo%
```

The only difference I can see between these two implementations is the sock_fd address is at a different spot in memory.  This makes no sense to me.  Someone tell me I'm doing something else wrong.

It might be important that I'm running this on High Sierra 10.13.16, but I got the same result running on whatever *Nix OS my school's server is running.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not `sock_fd`.

The loop in your second example does *not* stop upon success. It just keeps looping until `p` is null.

And, you'll have a "dangling" open socket. For example, the first `bind` attempt succeeds, so `sock_fd` is *not* closed. But, now the second `bind` attempt fails because the address is in use from the first socket. But, the `sock_fd` value for the first attempt has already been overwritten by the `socket` call for the second value. So, the useful/first value for `sock_fd` has been trashed.

You need to reverse the sense of the `if` for your `bind` call to stop looping when `bind` succeeds.

You want:

```
if (bind(*sock_fd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) != -1)
    break;
// process bind error ...
```

---

Also, note that you do `free(servinfo)` before you return. Since this points to a linked list of structs, I believe this is incorrect/insufficient. It would only free the *first* one. You should [probably] use `freeaddrinfo(servinfo)` as recommended in the manpage.

But, either way, the returned value of `p` will be pointing to reclaimed/unusable memory.